# call google app script user defined method on JavaScript event

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps, google-slides

I have lot of anchor tags in html with attribute `data-action="someAction"`.
i want to call these action from 1 JavaScript on-click event like below :

But this test throwing error

```
Uncaught TypeError: google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(...).withFailureHandler(...).withUserObject(...).action is not a function
```

**Update:**

As i have checked `console.log(action)`  is a `string` type,
is there any way to make it as method of Google App Script so that my below script can work ?

**My script:**

```
$('.icon-action').on("click", function() {
    let action = $(this).attr("data-action");
      google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(
              function(returnSuccess, element) {
                  // return success
              })
          .withFailureHandler(
              function(msg, element) {
                   // return error
              })
          .withUserObject(this)
          .action();
  });
```

Comment: `action()` has to be a server side function.  Read about it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) And your code is definitely clients side code.

Comment: It's sort of simplified way of doing an httpRequest from webapp or dialog

Comment: @cooper Please help me with the answer to your suggested..

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Well... You need to work on data types in JavaScript and how data attributes work - all `data` props are strings. Since you use them as names of server-dide funcs to call, you need to treat them like strings - please read up on "computed properties" (what to do should become obvious once you take a quick look). Hint: `google.script.run` is an object

Comment: i tried to convert string to object but it not working.
actually i am new to google app script and also to JS , so if you can show me your suggestion with a sample working or some tricks , then i will more from this particle use. @OlegValter

Comment: @RoshanJha - I meant [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) :) Hint about an object refers to the `google.script.run` chain - it *results* in an object you need to index. Once you get a grasp on computed properties, will be a piece of cake

Comment: @OlegValter i got your point , also tried learn about above,but how this above hint will solve my issue, i cant say. may i request you to please share your idea as answer ? that would be really helpful in my learning curve.

Comment: `withUserObject(this)[action](<list of parameters here>)`. "action" is a variable *name*, why would you expect it to exist on the return type of `withUserObject` as one of the keys? Actual name is contained *in* the variable, hence the computed property (aka bracket notation) suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help and suggestion of  [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter)  i solved this issue.
for future users i am posting my working solution here.
Please refer to this comment  - [call google app script user defined method on JavaScript event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66159033/call-google-app-script-user-defined-method-on-javascript-event?noredirect=1#comment117042028_66159033)

```
$('.icon-action').on("click", function() {
    let action = $(this).attr("data-action");
      google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(
              function(returnSuccess, element) {
                  // return success
              })
          .withFailureHandler(
              function(msg, element) {
                   // return error
              })
          .withUserObject(this)[action]();
  });
```